# MVC2 throws InvalidOperationException in UpdateModel(), trying to update the id field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, channel

My MVC2 app is giving me grief today...  I want to edit a database record, using the following Controller code:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post), Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public virtual ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection formValues)
    {
        var masterDataProxy = MasterDataChannelFactory.OpenChannel();
        var tester = masterDataProxy.GetTester(id);
        masterDataProxy.CloseChannel();

        if (null == tester)
        {
            return View(Views.NotFound);
        }

        try
        {
            UpdateModel(tester);

            var adminProxy = AdminChannelFactory.OpenChannel();
            adminProxy.AddUpdateTester(tester);
            adminProxy.CloseChannel();

            return RedirectToAction(Actions.Index());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Tester", ex.Message);

            return View(tester);
        }
    }
```

I'm getting the high-level exception "The model of type 'Model.Entity' could not be updated", and when I drill down into the ModelState I see it's failing when trying to update the Id field -- "Setting the Id property is only supported with .NET 3.5+ during entity deserialization".

The question is, how can I tell UpdateModel() not to update the Id field?  I don't want it to update that field!!

Any ideas?
Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
UpdateModel(tester, formValues.ToValueProvider());
```

and make sure `Id` is not included in the formValues.

Answer (score 0):

Use `TryUpdateModel(tester)` insted of `UpdateModel(tester)`

Comment: Doesn't that just fail without an exception?  I may have a faulty understanding of what Try..() methods do, but I thought they just fail in a nicer way.  It still doesn't solve the underlying problem...

Comment: Try..() just does not throw InvalidOperation exception. So, I may be wrong here. @Bala's answer may help.