# MVC3 UpdateModel - Setting the Id property is only supported with .NET 3.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, lightspeed

Getting an error caught in UpdateModel

"Setting the Id property is only supported with .NET 3.5+ during entity deserialization" System.Exception {System.NotSupportedException}

```
public ActionResult Edit1(Guid id, ActivityResponseConsumerMobile arcm) {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
            SetupDropDowns();
            return View(arcm);
        }

        ActivityResponseConsumerMobile arcmDb = uow.ActivityResponseConsumerMobiles.Single(a => a.Id == id);
        try {
            UpdateModel(arcmDb);
        }
        catch {
            var x = ModelState;
            return View(arcm);
        }
```

Feels like SO Question:  [MVC2 throws InvalidOperationException in UpdateModel(), trying to update the id field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916348/mvc2-throws-invalidoperationexception-in-updatemodel-trying-to-update-the-id)

but I'm using the object instead of FormCollection.  ORM I'm using is LightSpeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking good so far with putting in an exclusion..

```
UpdateModel(arcmDb, null, null, new[] {"Id"});
```

It turns out this is not an MVC issue as I had the same issue using AutoMapper elsewhere in the app, and had to exclude the ID there too.

```
   Mapper.CreateMap<ActivityPushConsumerMobile, ActivityPushConsumerMobile>()
                              .ForMember(dest => dest.EntityState, opt => opt.Ignore())
                              .ForMember(x => x.Id, y => y.Ignore())
```

Unsure as to what has changed since it worked.  Possible upgrade from LightSpeed3 to 4.  And am using .NET4 framework.